# Redirect(URl) provides controller\view\URI pattern

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Redirect(URl) provides "controller\view\URI" pattern but I want only URI

Answer (score 0):

That's easy!

Go to RouteConfig.cs and before

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

put a line:

```
    routes.MapRoute("SignUp", "signup", new { controller = "SignUp", action = "Index" });
```

Where:

- SignUp - route name, to be used with RedirectToRoute
- signup - your URI
- controller and action are self explanatory

Comment: would you give an example?